# Get a substring from a list item in python after a word

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am using BeautifulSoup to get the title of a book from a goodreads page.

Sample HTML -

```
<td class="field title"><a href="/book/show/12996.Othello" title="Othello">
  Othello
</a></td>
```

I want to get the text between the anchor tags. Using the code below, I can get all the children of  with class="field title" in a list form.

```
for txt in soup.findAll('td',{'class':"field title"}):
    child = txt.findAll('a')
```

which gives output-

```
[<a href="/book/show/12996.Othello" title="Othello">
  Othello
</a>]
...
```

How do I get the 'Othello' part only? This regex doesn't work -

```
for ch in child:
    match = re.search(r"([.]*)title=\"<name>\"([.]*)",str(ch))
    print(match.group('name'))
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [Beautiful Soup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Comment: @goelakash, do you want the **string** between `<a> ... </a>` or the **title** 's `Othello`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edited:

Just print the text of `txt` (thanks for @angurar clarifying OP's requirements):

```
for txt in soup.findAll('td',{'class':"field title"}):
    print txt.string
```

Or if you're after the title attribute of `<a>`:

```
for txt in soup.findAll('td',{'class':"field title"}):
    print [a.get('title') for a in txt.findAll('a')]
```

It will return a list of all `<a>` title's attribute.

Comment: Or use `a.string` to get the nested text.

Comment: @augurar, I think OP wants the `title` attribute, not the string, otherwise just `print txt.text` would do

Comment: Quoth the OP, "I want to get the text between the anchor tags."

Comment: @augurar, thanks for clarifying this, I re-read OP and yes you're right. Too many `Othello` confused me :)